# How to compare the result of cmd in the vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, cmd, compare

I ask about getting  the result of this cmd command  **netstat -a | find /c "TCP"**

and compare it with specific value  using VBSCRIPT

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer question with so less details, but lets try anyway...

Example code below will illustrate 2 ways to store the command-line output to a variable in your vbs. `WScript.Echo` is used just as evidence (display the result).

```
'** VAR#1 (using Exec & StdOut) ----------
Dim ObjExec
Dim strFromProc

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ObjExec = objShell.Exec("%comspec% /c " _
    & "netstat -a | find /c " & Chr(34) & "TCP" & Chr(34))

Do Until ObjExec.Stdout.atEndOfStream
    strFromProc = strFromProc & ObjExec.StdOut.ReadLine & vbNewLine
Loop

WScript.Echo strFromProc ' display result from variable strFromProc

Set objShell = Nothing
Set ObjExec = Nothing

'** VAR#2 (using Run) --------------------
Const cLogFile = "result.txt"

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%comspec% /c netstat -a | find /c " _
    & Chr(34) & "TCP" & Chr(34) & ">" & cLogFile, 0, True

Dim oFile, Result
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If .FileExists(cLogFile) Then
        Set oFile = .OpenTextFile(cLogFile)
        Result = oFile.ReadLine
        oFile.Close
        Set oFile = .GetFile(cLogFile)
        oFile.Delete
    End If
End With

WScript.Echo Result ' display result from variable Result

Set oFile = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
```